# Python select.select without pausing execution

Tags: python, sockets

I have a while loop containing select which pauses execution. I also need the server to be able to send data once per second. With the while loop being held up by the select I can't implement this message being sent. I was hoping to be able to do it in one thread without having to create a new one for sending.

```py
while True:
    read_sockets, _, exception_sockets = select.select(sockets_list, [], sockets_list)
    #Code for receiving messages
    if (one second has passed since last loop):
        client_socket.send(header + message)
```

Comment: `select.select` takes an optional fourth argument, which is a timeout. If you don't want to wait, set a short or zero timeout. If it timed out, it will return a tuple of empty lists.

Comment: Could you write this as the answer and I'll mark it as such

Comment: Okay, will do, but I don't have time to do any more than copy and paste. Normally I would hope to offer more detail if I was writing it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(OP requested that I write this as an answer.)*

`select.select` takes an optional fourth argument, which is a timeout. If you don't want to wait, set a short or zero timeout. If it timed out, it will return a tuple of empty lists.